# How can I fix my corrupted /data partition?

Tags: unbricking, partitions

The following happened. I have a Galaxy Mini Plus (S5570I) running Android 2.3.6 which I've been using without problems so far. Recently, I've installed an APK (Opera Beta), which somehow caused the device to freeze, so I had to pull the battery out and restart it manually. Upon switching it back, the device stays at the pre-boot screen, and constantly displays the "Samsung Galaxy Mini" logo, the one that's supposed to show up for seconds before the boot animation. No amount of waiting or restarting helps, it's completely bricked for some reason.

However, if I try to restore a backup via Clockworkmod, or try to erase the information, I immediately receive an error saying `Error mounting /data!` or `Can't mount /data!`. Every single other partition loads and is mountable, except for /data. Which renders backup, restore, or delete impossible.

Is there a way I could manually rewrite the partition table (i.e. recreate the partitions) or somehow get the device to boot, preferably without sending it in for repair? Clockworkmod doesn't work, stock service mode doesn't work, Odin doesn't work, I can't even get adb connected.

Comment: Looks like your `/data` partition got corrupted. Are there any more detailed error messages? Do you get into CWM at all? Any chance to get to a shell prompt? If "No-to-all", you might be left with a fresh install (e.g. via `fastboot`). Which brings me to an idea: AFAIK one can use `fastboot` to let the device load/boot an image from the computer, which might give you a chance to access the shell and repair the broken partition. Havin no experience with that part, I can only leave the idea in the hope someone else picks it up...

Comment: Fastboot doesn't work with Samsung devices. To try and restore a stock image, you would want to use odin and find a factory image for your device. I'm not too familiar with Samsung devices, so I'll leave it up to someone a bit more knowledgeable to give you the proper steps.

Comment: Yep, I can access CWM (only from a zip file though, since my device doesn't support embedding it), but I haven't been able to get any more detailed messages or logs out of it. If I try to invoke any function that would write/read from the /data partition, I simply get a one line error saying that it can't be mounted. Same if I try to view the log from within Clockworkmod. However, I got the "report error" function to output a log to my sdcard (Full log here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26401476/recovery.log), which still doesn't tell me much about WHY the partition isn't being mounted.

Comment: As for the Odin stock restore, I've seen it recommended on a couple forums so far, although I haven't really been successful in finding either a working copy of the software, or a suitable image for my device (5570I). Damn, there has to be some way to fix the partitions using a script or something. I don't even know how shit like this could happen. The data is still there, Android just refuses to access it.